# I am getting error in using the Python script which is designed to split Excel based on column categories

Tags: python, excel

Please help, I am trying to create separate files based on company column, I ran the filescript using CMD,

This screenshot is a sample of my data, where in every day I have to filter and create new Excel file according to company and send email to, I want to automate this with Python:

[image: Screenshot]

I am getting error when separating as file

C:\Users\sudarshan\Desktop>py filesplit.py

File Path: C:\Users\sudarshan\Desktop\Sample.xlsx

Select Column: Company

You data will split based on these values Medlife B2B Cargo, TWIN BIRDS, Allied Moulded Enclosure Products, JMZ CARGO PVT LTD and create 4 files or sheets based on next selection. If you are ready to proceed please type "Y" and hit enter. Hit "N" to exit.
Ready to Proceed (Y/N): y

Split into different Sheets or File (S/F): F

Error starts from here and this error message show after i input "F" for the above line.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\sudarshan\Desktop\filesplit.py", line 49, in <module>
    sendtofile(cols)
  File "C:\Users\sudarshan\Desktop\filesplit.py", line 24, in sendtofile
    df[df[colpick] == i].to_excel("{}/{}.xlsx".format(pth, i), sheet_name=i, index=False)
  File "C:\python\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 2188, in to_excel
    formatter.write(
  File "C:\python\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\formats\excel.py", line 821, in write
    writer.write_cells(
  File "C:\python\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\excel\_xlsxwriter.py", line 209, in write_cells
    wks = self.book.add_worksheet(sheet_name)
  File "C:\python\lib\site-packages\xlsxwriter\workbook.py", line 184, in add_worksheet
    return self._add_sheet(name, worksheet_class=worksheet_class)
  File "C:\python\lib\site-packages\xlsxwriter\workbook.py", line 735, in _add_sheet
    name = self._check_sheetname(name, isinstance(worksheet, Chartsheet))
  File "C:\python\lib\site-packages\xlsxwriter\workbook.py", line 784, in _check_sheetname
    raise InvalidWorksheetName(
xlsxwriter.exceptions.InvalidWorksheetName: Excel worksheet name 'Allied Moulded Enclosure Products' must be <= 31 chars.
```

below is the python script for filesplit

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# coding: utf-8

# In[ ]:


import pandas as pd
import os
from openpyxl import load_workbook
import xlsxwriter
from shutil import copyfile

file=input('File Path: ')
extension = os.path.splitext(file)[1]
filename = os.path.splitext(file)[0]
pth=os.path.dirname(file)
newfile=os.path.join(pth,filename+'_2'+extension)
df=pd.read_excel(file)
colpick=input('Select Column: ')
cols=list(set(df[colpick].values))

def sendtofile(cols):
    for i in cols:
        df[df[colpick] == i].to_excel("{}/{}.xlsx".format(pth, i), sheet_name=i, index=False)
    print('\nCompleted')
    print('Thanks for using this program.')
    return

def sendtosheet(cols):
    copyfile(file, newfile)
    for j in cols:
        writer = pd.ExcelWriter(newfile, engine='openpyxl')
        for myname in cols:
            mydf = df.loc[df[colpick] == myname]
            mydf.to_excel(writer, sheet_name=myname, index=False)
        writer.save()

    print('\nCompleted')
    print('Thanks for using this program.')
    return

print('You data will split based on these values {} and create {} files or sheets based on next selection. If you are ready to proceed please type "Y" and hit enter. Hit "N" to exit.'.format(', '.join(cols),len(cols)))
while True:
    x=input('Ready to Proceed (Y/N): ').lower()
    if x == 'y':
        while True:
            s = input('Split into different Sheets or File (S/F): ').lower()
            if s == 'f':
                sendtofile(cols)
                break
            elif s == 's':
                sendtosheet(cols)
                break
            else: continue
        break
    elif x=='n':
        print('\nThanks for using this program.')
        break

    else: continue


# In[ ]:
```

Files link
https://github.com/sudarshan0091/filesplit

Please note this script is not mine got it from github, it is of youtube trainer.

Comment: Use a shorter sheet name. You've surpassed the character limit.

Comment: And the error message said EXACTLY that.  Couldn't you see that?

Comment: Yes Tim , i noticed that now, i could not understand that at first, actually i am new to this programing world and just googling to make my life easy for my every day excel work.
Thank you, for your response.

Answer (score 1):

The maximum allowable worksheet name in Excel is 31 characters.
The worksheet name you are trying to use is longer than that. Hence the error message.

Comment: Thank you for the response, please help, how do i change the code, so that file can split without changing worksheet name(i meant worksheet name can be with its default name and only file name can be changed). 
can that be possible?